# xmlstarlet select value

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

This is the xml-data:

```
<DATA VERSION="1.0">
  <TABLES>
    <ITEM>
      <identifyer V="1234"></identifyer>
      <property1 V="abcde"></property1>
      <Property2 V="qwerty"></property2>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <identifyer V="5678"></identifyer>
      <Property1 V="zyxwv"></property1>
      <Property2 V="dvorak"></property2>
    </ITEM>
  </TABLES>
</DATA>
```

I am trying to find `property2` of the item where `identifyer` has value `1234`. I can select the data:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/DATA/TABLES/ITEM/identifyer [@V=1234]" test.xml 
<identifyer V="1234"/>
```

Two types of output would be desirable:

```
$ xmlstarlet <some magic>
<identifyer V="1234"></identifyer>
<property1 V="abcde"></property1>
<Property2 V="qwerty"></property2>
```

And:

```
$ xmlstarlet <some magic>
qwerty
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The key is to start from the ITEM node, not the identifyer:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/DATA/TABLES/ITEM[identifyer/@V=1234]" test.xml
<ITEM>
  <identifyer V="1234"/>
  <property1 V="abcde"/>
  <Property2 V="qwerty"/>
</ITEM>
```

Then you can pick out the bits you want:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/DATA/TABLES/ITEM[identifyer/@V=1234]/*" test.xml
<identifyer V="1234"/><property1 V="abcde"/><Property2 V="qwerty"/>

$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/DATA/TABLES/ITEM[identifyer/@V=1234]/Property2/@V" test.xml
qwerty
```

Comment: Great, that works :) Good to see the syntax in an example, I can get forward with this. Thanks!