# xmlstarlet: how to select items to build a hash

Tags: xml, bash, hash, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I would like to extract (using `xmlstarlet`) from the following XML file (list.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reports>
  <report>
    <name>b486f8d9</name>
    <readableName>Scan1</readableName>
    <timestamp>1375757990</timestamp>
  </report>
  <report>
    <name>5f01bd96</name>
    <readableName>Scan2</readableName>
    <timestamp>1367342696</timestamp>
  </report>
</reports>
```

the value of `readableName` for a given `name`. In the example above this would be `Scan1` for a query on `b486f8d9`.

I found [a great answer on a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640152/xmlstarlet-select-value) but the query is on another type of elements, then tried

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/reports/report[name=b486f8d9]" list.xml
```

but this did not work (empty output)

Could you please help me to construct the appropriate query for my case? Since I ultimately want to build a hash in bash (the key being `name` and values `readableName` and `timestamp`) maybe there is a more clever way to do that instead of parsing the file the way I intend to (= first get the list of `name`s, then query the values for each of them)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison:

```
name=b486f8d9
```

Compares the value of the tag `name` with the value of the element `b486f8d9`. Since there is no element `b486f8d9`, that's not going to work. What you wanted was to compare the element `name` with the string `'b486f8d9'`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/reports/report[name='b486f8d9']"
```

But that's going to get you a chunk of XML (since it's a -**c**opy of the selected element). What you want is the string -**v**alue of the `readableName` element:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/reports/report[name='b486f8d9']/readableName"
```

which will print

```
Scan1
```

So that's how you do a lookup. But I believe you want to do a full report of all of the names. You can create pretty well any format you like; here's one example (note the use of -**m**atch to match all `/reports/report` elements.)

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/reports/report" \
                 -v name -o ' ' -v readableName -o ':' -v timestamp -n list.xml
b486f8d9 Scan1:1375757990
5f01bd96 Scan2:1367342696
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you. I will see how to best integrated this into the hash (but I guess iterating will be the way to go)