# extract data sed or grep or awk from xml

Tags: xml, csv, awk, sed, grep

I have the following xml. I need to extract the IP address, protocol and port into a CSV file with the corresponding column names.

```
<rule family="ipv4">
<source address="10.XXX.XX.XX"/>
<port protocol="tcp" port="22"/>
<log prefix="ber_" level="warning">
<limit value="1/m"/>
</log>
<accept/>
</rule>
<rule family="ipv4">
<source address="10.XXX.XX.XXX"/>
<port protocol="udp" port="1025"/>
<log prefix="ber_" level="warning">
<limit value="1/m"/>
</log>
<accept/>
```

I'm able to grep IP address or the port using grep or sed like this `grep -Eo "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"` But I need it as columns in CSV file.

IPAddress Protocol Port . What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Get values using XPath. On Linux, you can use xmllint for that.

Comment: You cannot generally parse XML with regular expressions, as has been discussed hundreds of times on this site.  If you want robust code that will not fail when the input format changes slightly you must use an XML parser to load the DOM, or an XPath evaluator.  Either Perl or Python have everything you will need.

Comment: Please, provide **REAL** xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get attribute value using xmlstarlet or xmllint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595262/get-attribute-value-using-xmlstarlet-or-xmllint)

Answer (score 2):

Dont' use regex to parse html/xml, but a real parser (using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath)):

#### Corrected wrong input xml file :

```
<root>
    <rule family="ipv4">
        <source address="10.XXX.XX.XX"/>
        <port protocol="tcp" port="22"/>
        <log prefix="ber_" level="warning">
            <limit value="1/m"/>
        </log>
    </rule>
    <rule family="ipv4">
        <source address="10.XXX.XX.XXX"/>
        <port protocol="udp" port="1025"/>
        <log prefix="ber_" level="warning">
            <limit value="1/m"/>
        </log>
    </rule>
</root>
```

#### Code :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//source/@address | //port/@protocol | //port/@port' file |
perl -pe '$. % 3 != 0 && s/\n/,/g;END{print "\n"}'
```

#### Output :

```
10.XXX.XX.XX,tcp,22
10.XXX.XX.XXX,udp,1025
```

#### theory :

According to the compiling theory, HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php)

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) (my own project)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Instead of this, how can I get in columns?

Comment: Don't know what you mean

Comment: The output is 10.XXX.XX.XX
tcp
22

Answer (score 0):

lacking xml tools, here is a fragile `awk` solution

```
1$ awk -v RS='</rule>' '
       {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
          if($i~/^(address|protocol|port)/) 
            {split($i,a,"\""); printf "%s", a[2] (++c%3?FS:ORS)}}' file

10.XXX.XX.XX tcp 22
10.XXX.XX.XXX udp 1025
```