# How do I update <path> in my XML according to the given file name

Tags: xml, linux, xmlstarlet

```
<annotation>
  <folder>cars_train</folder>
  <filename>00001.jpg</filename>
  <path>Users/hantaoliu/Documents/Research/cars_train/.jpg</path>
  <source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
  </source>
  <size>
```

The text above is one of the XML file I want to update. I have 7k XML files and I want the path of them to be:

```
Users/hantaoliu/Documents/Research/cars_train/$@.jpg
```

`$@` corresponds to the name of the input file. For example, if the input file is `00001.xml`, I want the path to be:

```
Users/hantaoliu/Documents/Research/cars_train/00001.jpg
```

I'm using `xmlstarlet`, but I'm not able to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want like so. First select the value of `filename` and the value of `path`.

```
$ filenameVal=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/annotation/filename" file)
$ pathVal=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/annotation/path" file)
```

Next determine the directory name of `path` via the `$(dirname $pathVal)` and concatenate `$filenameVal` to it. You can do a test run of this without editing the file like so:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u "/annotation/path" -v "$(dirname $pathVal)/$filenameVal" file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<annotation>
  <folder>cars_train</folder>
  <filename>00001.jpg</filename>
  <path>Users/hantaoliu/Documents/Research/cars_train/00001.jpg</path>
  <source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
  </source>
  <size>
  </size>
</annotation>
```

If things look good you can add the `-L` switch which tells `xmlstartlet` to edit in place.

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -L -u "/annotation/path" -v "$(dirname $pathVal)/$filenameVal" file
```

Confirming the results in `file`:

```
$ cat file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<annotation>
  <folder>cars_train</folder>
  <filename>00001.jpg</filename>
  <path>Users/hantaoliu/Documents/Research/cars_train/00001.jpg</path>
  <source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
  </source>
  <size>
  </size>
</annotation>
```

#### References

- [xmlstartlet reference - 3. Editing XML documents](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html)
- [xmlstarlet select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640152/xmlstarlet-select-value)

Comment: Do I have to enter every individual filename to the file?

Comment: For example, in this step $ filenameVal=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/annotation/filename" file), Do I have to change the value of file in filenameVal if I am doing 00002.xml?

Comment: @LiuHantao - I wasn't sure what structure you had of the 7K files. You can use `find` or a Bash `for` loop to work through them and do the above.

Comment: @LiuHantao - that's correct, the above is a template of the approach. You need to loop through it over all your files to accomplish this.

Comment: How do I use a loop with xmlstarlet? A shell script?

Comment: @LiuHantao - correct, the looping would be handled by a shell script.