# xmlstarlet modify XML attribute in a body that also has an attribute with a specific value

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I am creating a bash script to replace various values in a large XML file using XMLStarlet.
For one specific situation I fail to find the proper XMLStarlet commandline syntax.

I created a simplified XML file (test.xml) to show my situation:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA VERSION="1.0">
  <TABLES>
    <ITEM>
      <ID>1234</ID>
      <prop3>ABCD</prop3>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <ID>5678</ID>
      <prop3>EFGH</prop3>
    </ITEM>
  </TABLES>
</DATA>
```

I am trying to replace prop3 of an ITEM with a specific ID (e.g. 5678).
I found a very similar question/reply on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640152/xmlstarlet-select-value) which gave me good hopes to bring me to the solution. It definitely helped but only partially.

I constructed the below command but it is not entirely right since it has no effect (XML unchanged):

```bash
xmlstarlet ed -u "/DATA/TABLES/ITEM[@ID='5678']/prop3" -v "succes" test.xml
```

Comment: `ITEM[@ID='5678']` matches a tag with an ID attribute like `<ITEM ID="5678">` but your sample xml document doesn't use attributes, thus nothing matches the xpath expression.

Comment: Make it look for a child element named ID instead by removing the `@`.

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer @Shawn

Comment: @glennjackman Now that I'm at a computer again, done.

Answer (score 1):

The XPath fragment `ITEM[@ID='5678']` looks for an `ITEM` element with a matching `ID` *attribute*: `<ITEM ID="5678">`. Your sample XML document doesn't use attributes on `ITEM` elements, thus nothing in it will match. To match an element with a matching *child element*, drop the `@` and it'll make the replacement:

```bash
$ xmlstarlet ed -u "/DATA/TABLES/ITEM[ID='5678']/prop3" -v "succes" test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA VERSION="1.0">
  <TABLES>
    <ITEM>
      <ID>1234</ID>
      <prop3>ABCD</prop3>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <ID>5678</ID>
      <prop3>succes</prop3>
    </ITEM>
  </TABLES>
</DATA>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone.

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/DATA/TABLES/ITEM[ID='5678']/prop3" -v "succes" test.xml
```

It works. I learned something more about XML.